# Group by one variable, but summary() over all other variables (mean) in R

Tags: r, group-by, mean

I know that there are already some threads about it, but I haven't found one yet about this specific problem. 
The dependent variable in my dataset is Y and I have 144 independent variables. Y and X can take only the values 1 or 0. The data looks like

```
          Y    A469 T593 K022K A835 Z935 U83F W5326  ...
 Person1  1      1    1    1     0    0    0    0
 Person2  1      0    1    0     1    1    0    0
 Person3  0      0    0    1     0    0    1    1
 ...
summary(dataset)
```

just provides descriptive statistics over all observations. What I want is (in pseudo-code):

```
summary(all variables if Y == 1 and Y == 0)
```

It would be great if I could see how often a certain X occurs in the certain value of Y. For example, mean(X4) = 0.04 and count = 6 if Y = 1.

Comment: Please provide a more complete data set to work with. You can and should use `dput` to provide sample data.

Comment: @NelsonGon Bold assertion after it's already been nearly answered. I'm all for reproducible examples, and of course `dput()` is nicer, but this is plenty clear.

Comment: @Gregor it seemed to me that lack of data was making it hard to find the "ideal" solution. My apologies!

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT 2**
after Akrun's and Gregor's comments here is the solution

```
 data_summary <- dataset %>% group_by(y) %>% 
    mutate(n = n()) %>%
    summarise_all(mean)
```

If you want to see more columns than fit on your screen you can try, e.g.,

- `print(data_summary, width = 20)`
- `View(data_summary)`
- `select(data_summary, <<particular columns you want to see>>)`
- ...

Comment: I'm getting this error message: 
Error in UseMethod("groups") : 
  no applicable method for 'groups' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Comment: can you please provide a sample of your data?

Comment: I think the `count` is the issue.   YOu may need `n()`

Comment: Still error
Error: n() should only be called in a data context
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace

Comment: try `n`instead of `n()`

Comment: Error: Can't create call to non-callable object
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace

Comment: Try `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise_all(list(~ mean(.), ~ n()))`

Comment: Since `n()` is the same for each column in the group, a nicer result might be to create it as its own column, e.g., `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% mutate(n = n()) %>% summarize_all(list(mean = mean))`

Comment: @Gregor that's the solution! But it only shows the first 10 variables and I have to stretch the results window and execute the command again to see more variables. I have 144 variables.

Comment: You're right, it only **shows** the first 10 variables. They are all there, they just aren't printed. Save the result as `data_summary` or something and look at it with something other than the default print method for tibbles. `print.data.frame(data_summary)`, `View(data_summary)`, `write.csv(data_summary)`, `print(data_summary, width = Inf)`, etc.

Comment: That works! The problem is that when using the summarise_all(list(~ mean(.), ~ n())) I'm getting the count of Y and not of each X in certain Y